# How to manipulate or transpose a dataset for use in R or SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I need to manipulate the raw data (csv) to a wide format so that I can analyze in R or SPSS.

It looks something like this:

```
1,age,30 
1,race,black 
1,scale_total,35
2,age,20
2,race,white
2,scale_total,99
```

Ideally it would look like:

```
ID,age,race,scale_total, etc
1, 30, black, 35 
2, 20, white, 99
```

I added values to the top row of the raw data (ID, Question, Response) and tried the cast function but I believe this aggregated data instead of just transforming it:

```
data_mod <- cast(raw.data2, ID~Question, value="Response")
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1):

We need a sequence column to be created to take care of the duplicate rows which by default results in aggregation to `length`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID + rowid(Question) ~ Question, value.var = 'Response')
```

NOTE: The example data clearly works (giving expected output) without using the sequence column.

```
dcast(setDT(df1), ID ~ Question)
#   ID age   race scale_total
#1:  1 30  black           35
#2:  2  20  white          99
```

So, this is a case when applied on the full dataset with duplicate rows

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Question = c("age", 
"race", "scale_total", "age", "race", "scale_total"), Response = c("30", 
 "black ", "35", "20", "white", "99")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Each ID may not necessarily have every Question variable associated with it, e.g., ID 1 may not have a race variable present but ID 2 and 3 do, because participants only viewed/answered applicable questions. How would you handle this if I wanted "NA" to fill in that "missing" data? When I run the script above, it creates multiple rows for some ID's. @andrew

Comment: @blacksheep  I think your message is meant for andrew

Comment: Apologies, I meant to reply to you. I used the code you provided but it created multiple rows for each ID and I wasn't sure a way around that.

Comment: @blacksheep  Is it based on the same example (as I couldn't reproduce)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tidyr`...

```
library(tidyr)
df<-read.csv(text="1,age,30 
    1,race,black 
    1,scale_total,35
    2,age,20
    2,race,white
    2,scale_total,99", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df %>% spread(key=V2,value=V3)

  V1 age   race scale_total
1  1 30  black           35
2  2  20  white          99
```

Answer (score 0):

For SPSS:

```
data list list/ID (f5) Question Response (2a20).
begin data
1 "age" "30" 
1 "race" "black" 
1 "scale_total" "35"
2 "age" "20"
2 "race" "white"
2 "scale_total" "99"
end data.

casestovars /id=id /index=question.
```

Note that the resulting variables `age` and `scale_total` will be string variables - you'll have to turn them into numbers before further transformations:

```
alter type age scale_total (f8).
```